# Does 'moonlighting' mean 'illegal work'?

Tags: meaning, translation

I was looking for the translation of the German word 'Schwarzarbeit' (black work) that means working illegally, without written contract, in order to avoid labour laws and taxation.

The Google Translator has proposed the word 'moonlighting', but from the context I know that word, it's more about doing illicit things like brewing alcohol without license.

Does 'moonlighting' have a (second) meaning that represents the meaning of 'Schwarzarbeit'?

Comment: [Have a second job, typically secretly and at night, in addition to one's regular employment.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/moonlight) Courtesy of Lexico.

Comment: UK uses a term similar to the German one: the [black economy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/black-economy) dodges legal procedures.

Comment: The common usage as I understand it is basically of a hidden second life. The policeman who moonlights as a drag-queen probably doesn't want his buddies to know about his secret second job, even if it's totally legal. Just for an example.

Comment: Just to be clear:  in American English, "moonshining" is the act of making "moonshine", which is alcohol distilled without a license.  "Moonlighting" does not necessarily involve alcohol.

Comment: I once spent less than a week working as a bartender (long story). At the end of my time, my employer and I both agreed it wasn't working out, and he asked if it was OK if he just wrote me a check for my pay and listed it as "lawnmower repair". This saved us both the time/effort of all the paperwork to make me a "legal" employee for 4 days. I was paid "under the table" making this "black work". However, it was _not_ moonlighting, because it was my full time "day job" at the time and I had no other employment. "Moonlighting" would have meant that I was doing this as a 2nd job, which I wasn't.

Comment: I think moonlighting is just a second unknown or secret job. Does not have to be illegal. Just to work in the light of the moon, as opposed to in daytime as most jobs are carried out.

Comment: Note well that a second moonlighting job *often* means an unusual job, perhaps treated somewhat privately.  But it absolutely **is not always used that way**. It's perfectly normal to use moonlighting in an entirely positive, ordinary way.  (You might hear, "the doctor moonlights as a freelance computer programmer on weekends" - that sort of thing.)

Comment: It is interesting that there emerges on this page a very definite split of opinions on the meaning of *moonlighting*. Some people are confident that it means a second job, with no further implications. Others are equally confident that it carries an implication of there being something shady or undesirable (although not necessarily Illegal) about the job. Perhaps the word is used differently in different circles.

Comment: @jsw29 the English speaking world is very big, different regions within it may very well have different usages. I'm providing a US West coast perspective.

Comment: @LorenPechtel hadn't thought of it, I think you're right. I guess the chances of having two completely unrelated jobs that you like are so low, that I erroneously "factored out" a negativity factor from all the usages I've come across lol.

Comment: I've never understood "moonlighting" to be secret or illegal or off the books. To me it's always meant what we'd call nowadays having a "side hustle".  For example, I've said things like "I have a job as a software developer but I also moonlight writing tech articles."

Comment: Not illegal, but have all those saying no 'shady' connotations checked their employment contracts.? It may be more open now than before - and will likely become more so in the so-called 'gig economy', but there is a definite link to some hiding in the original word.  Shady, shrouded, undercover of the night, dark arts - if the sun's not up *something* dodgy is going on, even just embarrassment about wearing some mascot suit. The US may see it differently: a moonlighter was also one who went about [serenading on moonlit nights](https://www.etymonline.com/word/moonlight).  But meanings change.

Comment: And a "light mooning" is when you show somebody your butt, but *not all* of it.

Comment: Why is this question not closed?  It is an utterly trivial question for the ELL site.  "Glance in a dictionary." Everyone knows that google translation is crap, does this site now allow "hey there's a crap translation on google" observations?

Comment: I have edited away the completely incorrect 2nd paragraph. This "glance in a dictionary" question needs to be closed anyway.  If anyone wants to re-edit, go for it.

Comment: Rolled back the edit, this is the OP's impression and initial thoughts. It explains why they felt compelled to ask the question in the first place. The *answers* can say why the 2nd paragraph is wrong, (in their opinion) that's why more on Stack one or more answers can be posted @Fattie. There's no need to get so heated up, chillax.

Comment: @Fattie, the very extent of activity on this page proves that this is not a trivial, glance-in-a-dictionary question. It calls for an interpretation of what can be found in dictionaries and sensitivity to the subtleties of current usage that go beyond the dictionary definitions.

Comment: @jsw29 its not a big deal but on this site "endless discussion" in fact *goes with* pointless questions that should be closed and usually are.  If you *literally* glance in the OED that comes with every single computer on Earth, the question is utterly, totally, and completely resolved. The definition could not be clearer. Pls see the edit to my answer just now ...

Comment: Also note that the endless discussion is about a side issue, not the question

Comment: Although nobody on this page wants to defend translating *Schwarzarbeit* as *moonlighting*, and I don't want to do it either, a film entitled *Moonligting*, from 1982, was released in Germany under the title *Schwarzarbeit*. Its German title is, in fact, more apt than the original, English one, as the film is about the work done by foreigners without employment authorisations, not the work done at a second job (unless one were to count the jobs in their country of origin as their first jobs).

Comment: Related: [Does "moonlighting" have a negative or neutral connotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152298).

Comment: My experience is this:  As a child in 1960s England, moonlighting definitely had connotations of work off the books, intentionally out of sight of the authorities.  Nowadays, here in California, moonlighting means an above board second job.  The physicians at my local hospital often do extra work through an agency.  They call it moonlighting.  Sometimes the moonlighting is back at the same hospital filling in for someone on leave or an unfilled vacancy.  The hospital is happy: the physicians are already licensed, insured and have admitting privileges at the hospital.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

While there used to be a criminal meaning for the word, that connotation is long gone:

> Moonlight is the reflection of the sun off the moon's surface — a clear sky and a full moon provide brilliant moonlight. Smugglers hate moonlight. If you moonlight, you work a second job, and it doesn’t have to be at night. If your history teacher also works as a mascot for a baseball team, he moonlights as a dancing bear. As a verb, it used to mean “commit crimes at night,” but now just means “to work a second job.” — [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/moonlight)

Moonlighting is legal (with a few exceptions that aren't that important here).

Note: that's not the same as [moonshine](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/moonshine), which is typically a noun (but is [sometimes used as a verb](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/moonshined#:%7E:text=Verb,illegally%3B%20produce%20moonshine)).

The phrase you are looking for is "work ***under the table***":

> To work in exchange for payment that is not officially documented and has not been taxed. — [Farlex via TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work+under+the+table)

That is illegal (as far as I know).

Comment: Yes, and "off the books" is also often used for undocumented / untaxed work.

Comment: I feel like "working under the table" is more commonly expressed as being "paid under the table".

Comment: "unless the income is considered a **gift**, you need to report all income *that is subject* to US taxation on your tax return. The $600 limit is just the IRS requirement for Form 1099-MISC to be considered necessary to file by the **payer**." https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/taxes/discussion/do-i-have-to-report-income-under-600/00/600250 - it's illegal for the *employer* - and illegal for both only if it isn't a "gift" or it's more than $10k annually. Not all income is subject. That's why Andy Dufresne didn't get tossed off a roof. Tax *evasion* is illegal. Not paying taxes isn't.

Comment: Good answer, but I do think that "moonshine" can be used as a verb in some contexts.  At the very least, it is natural to talk about the act of "moonshining", and to refer to people who do so as "moonshiners".

Comment: @Mazura good luck convincing any tax body that any money from a company was a gift.  It's a nice idea, but they'll argue that a gift is provided with no strings.  If someone has done work for that company, demonstrating that it wasn't performance related - and therefor had strings attached implicitly - is going to be pretty much impossible.


As for is moonlighting legal - It's generally not really, that's why it has to be kept secret.  That said, there's not a REQUIREMENT for it to be so, it's just a very likely reason for it.

Comment: @UKMonkey or it would be embarrassing if people at the "regular" job found out. Or if family/friends found out.

Comment: Although moonlighting doesn't imply illegality, I think that it is misleading to define it as nothing more than working a second job; the word still carries an implication of something somewhat clandestine. Somebody who moonlights need not hide that fact from the authorities, but typically does not make it widely known at one's primary workplace (because, although not illegal in itself, it may be against the rules of one's employment there, or perhaps because it is likely to be perceived as unseemly by one's colleagues).

Comment: @UKMonkey I've been at company parties where they had raffles -- I don't think the prizes were considered wages that needed to be reported. They weren't compensation for work.

Comment: @jsw29 While the term may have originally carried that connotation more strongly, I would say that that implication is at best very weak in current usage in the U.S. today, at least. It is common in my experience for people to refer to any secondary job as "moonlighting" when there's nothing clandestine about it and everything is purely above-board and known both legally and with one's employer(s).

Comment: @jsw29 you're right that it is common to use it in a negative, "secret work" sense, but it's also perfectly common to use it completely neutrally (just as reirab says).  The important point for the OP is there's just no connection at all to being paid under the table.

Comment: My landlord keeps me around with a discounted rent because I am willing to moonlight for him. Two weeks ago, the temps were in the mid 90s all week and I spent the week moonlighting as an a/c tech because I have a refrigeration license. Full time college students moonlight as bartenders and waiters, as opposed to co-opping in their intended field. There isn't any implied meaning beyond second job or extra employment. In todays parlance - side hustle.

Comment: "Cash in hand" means the same thing if accompanied with a wink and/or nudge.

Comment: @Barmar Was the raffle open to the general public, could anyone take part?  If not - it's compensation for work, and if the company were to follow taxes to the letter, they'd have to pay tax on it as a gift in kind.

Comment: @UKMonkey No, it was just for employees who attended the party. Was the party itself also compensation?

Answer (score 5):

It originally referred to the Australian/Irish expression meaning to steal cattle; thus ***[moonlighting](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/5kmr6mq)*** noun.

It was later used to refer to:

> (UK Und.) to engage in criminal activity at night.
>
> - 1942    [US]    Berrey & Van den Bark Amer. Thes. Sl.
> - 1949    [US]    Monteleone Criminal Sl. (rev. edn).

and to probably illegal but not criminal jobs.

> (orig. US) to work at two jobs in order to boost one’s income. The second job is usu. night work, and the other employer may not know about it; thus more usual as the noun moonlighting.
>
> - 1970    [US]    E. Tidyman Shaft 35: *Cops were moonlighting as armed cab drivers.*
> - 1978    [US]    L. Kramer Faggots 116: *He moonlighted, writing twice-monthly features.*

(GDoS)

Comment: _OED_ mentions the original sense as "The practice of mustering wild cattle at night." and provides a citation as early as 1880. The stealing of cattle might be a later sense. In Australia, they mustered wild cattle at night because they would come into clearing to graze at night and the stockmen needed sufficient moonlight to be able to do it. I've also found an old Australian language book talking about moonlighting as a method of mustering scrubbers at night; and even the shooting of possums seen in the tree branches under moonlight.

Comment: @ermanen - te original usage I’m referring to is the “illegal” one in which the OP is interested. I don’t think “mustering” had anything to do with illegal activities, from  which “stealing cattle” is most likely derived.

Comment: Yes, I'm just giving additional info about the history of the word. It has an interesting origin indeed. However, the sense of "to steal cattle" is not apparent; even from the examples in GDoS.

Comment: @ermanen - interesting, I've always thought 'scrubbers' was another name for prostitutes...

Comment: @Tim _Scrubber_ is an Aus./NZ term used for a person or animal that lives in the scrub. It is mostly used for wild cattle living in the scrub within this context. Per _OED_, _scrub_ is used for a breed of cattle also but it has a North American usage. _Scrub_ also has the slang usage "a disreputable woman; a prostitute, tart." as listed in _OED_.

Comment: This answer, discussing extremely archaic uses of a word, would be highly confusing to the OP; further, the whole answer does not even tough on the question asked.  The question asled is "does 'moonlighting' mean tax evasion". The answer can be given in two letters.

Comment: Since this answer seems intent to provide better context to the etymology of "moonlighting" versus its current usage... it is probably worth showing the [Google Ngram for "moonlighting"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moonlighting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=7).

The 1880-1900 period would seem to indicate the coinage of the phrase in relation to literal "crimes by moonlight" before usage drops off for the next few decades.  The post-WWII period (to present) is likely to be used as a figurative callback to that idea rather than meant literally.

Answer (score 5):

Moonlighting means **a second job**.

That's all it means.

This is **remarkably unarguably, straightforwardly, stated in the Oxford English Dictionary**:

[image]

> verb (past and past participle moonlighted) [no object] informal
> have a second job in addition to one's regular employment: many instructors moonlight as professional consultants. - The OED.

For example, a very famous TV show (actually, the funniest TV comedy ever made in the US) was named Moonlighting - a fashion model ended up working in a completely different field, for comic reasons.

(Please note that on this site, extensive discussion about the origin of, or previous meanings of, a word - **when the question is "What Does This Word Mean"** - lead to confusion.)

Regarding Schwarzarbeit.

In English you simply say "working off the books" or "working for cash" or you might hear "cash in hand", "under the table", "off the books"; the phrase "the black economy" is used to describe that overall economy. There's no single term for working "cash in hand".

(Moonlighting is utterly unrelated and does not suggest it in any way.)

Comment: I think there is also a connotation that the person is less skilled at the second job. "Moonlighting as an X" has the connotation that they're kind of masquerading as X, and not particularly good at it.

Comment: Maddie was forced into the detective agency owning job after being ripped off by her accountant - she was no longer a model.  The fact that it was a step down employment-wise in her mind does imply more than just 'a second job'.  Also, the show's name came from the fact that while a model, Maddie was known as the 'Blue Moon Shampoo girl' so they called it the 'Blue Moon Detective Agency'.  While there is a connection between the topic question and the name of the show, the fact that neither protagonist was actually working a second job kind of invalidates its use as evidence.

Comment: In the show, it was a second job. Moonlighting means a second job. That's all it means.  There is utterly no connection, at all, in any way, even slightly, to "working off the books to avoid tax".  In this site, it's a huge problem when discussions veer from the actual question at hand. The actual question at hand is "does 'moonlighting' mean tax evasion". Answer: no, utterly unconnected.

Comment: While there are dictionary definitions that say that moonlighting is a just a second job, there are those that add something like 'typically secretly and at night' (Lexico). The disagreements on this page are reasonable disagreements about how much weight should be given to *typically* in such definitions.

Comment: the OP's comment "it's more about doing illicit things like brewing alcohol without license" is wholly off base.  the answer to the OPs actual question is "No". the confusing side discussion about "ways moonlighting is used" is wholly irrelevant to anything I'm afraid !!!

Answer (score 3):

Others have given the correct denotation of "moonlighting" currently - a second job, one that possibly your main employer doesn't know about.  For tax purposes, it definitely is different than being paid under the table (by your main or secondary employer) in that it's legal work and paid and taxed legally.

However, many employers take the same sort of dim view of "moonlighting" as the taxman does of "Schwarzarbeit", and if they find out about it, it will negatively impact your main job (overlooked for promotions, not given plum work, on the list for being found not performing to expectations: "he always seems so tired").  If you moonlight in the same field as you're being paid for, they may be in the right, or at least able to restrict it in the contract. If it's totally different, the company's actions may not be legal, but it happens anyway, and you'll never be able to prove anything; and companies where this attitude holds are ones where you really want to keep your moonlighting on as much of a lowdown as you would if your moonlighting job *was* illegal or being paid "under the table".

As Mari-Lou A and Ruadhan2300 mention in their comments to the OP, "moonlighting" implies not just working a second job, but keeping it secret from someone (usually your main employer or the public) - and frequently having a reason to (the policeman moonlighting as a drag queen, as mentioned in the comments, or someone working for an employer known to frown on "hobby jobs").

Answer (score 1):

You indicated you were looking for a translation of *Schwarzarbeit*, meaning illegal “black work.”  A close equivalent is “working on the black market,” which Merriam-Webster defines as

> illicit trade in goods or commodities in violation of official regulations

Another possibility is working “under-the-table,” which the same dictionary defines as;

> covert and usually unlawful

The connotation here is slightly different.  Someone taking part in a black market is definitely exchanging illegal goods or services.  Someone getting paid under the table could mean they’re doing an innocuous job, but (for example) their income is not being reported so as to evade taxes.

Answer (score 1):

The colloquial word *moonlighting* (from 1954, originally *U.S.*, *moonlighter* for the person doing it) for a secondary paid work (often at night) in addition to one's regular job is a given per current usage and dictionaries; however, the origin and the history of the word can give us a glare of its multifarious semantic development, helping us to make sense of the current meaning.

In fact, the current usage is a positive semantic shift (amelioration) as an analogy to its origin, illicit activities done at night (under the moonlight). The sense 'illicit activity' is apparently still there as *OED* adds that this usage is rare, possibly used in Irish English only, in some isolated cases. Here is the earlier second sense of *moonlighting* (from 1882) from *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/121934?rskey=F2JHDi&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)*:

> The performance of an illicit action by night; *(Irish History)* the perpetration by night of raids on tenants who incurred the hostility of the Land League. Also *figurative*. Now *rare*.

Although, the earliest illicit activity sense, which is still in use, is **moonlight flit**; from 1824, defined in *OED* as:

> *n.* the act of leaving one's accommodation without paying the rent; the removal of household goods by night to avoid paying rent; (hence) a hurried departure or escape by night.

However, *OED* also has *moonlight flitting* from as early as 1721.

> *n.* Scottish (now *rare*) = *moonlight flit n*.

There is even a rare usage of *moonlight (n.)* meaning *moonshine (.n)* ('smuggled or illicitly distilled alcoholic liquor'), from 1809, according to *OED*; but adds that it is British regional.

Interestingly, there is an uncommon colloquial word *sunlighting* also (which I haven't heard before but found while searching), coined after *moonlighting*; from 1961, defined in *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/194122?redirectedFrom=sunlighting#eid)* as:

> *colloquial.* The practice of having a second job in addition to one's regular employment, which is undertaken during the day (rather than at night).

---

**Additional history:**

There is also the earliest sense of the noun *moonlighting* listed in *OED*, from 1880, which appears to be originated independently in Australian English; defined in *OED* as:

> *Australian.* The practice of mustering wild cattle at night.

In Australia, in old times, there was the practice of *moonlighting*, where they mustered wild cattle at night because they would come into clearing to graze at night and the stockmen needed sufficient moonlight to be able to see at night. Mustering is the act of collecting together wild cattle by riding round a scattered herd and driving it together. I've also found an  *[Australian language book](https://books.google.es/books/about/The_Australian_Language.html?id=27smAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)* (by Sidney John Baker) talking about *moonlighting* as a method of mustering scrubbers (wild cattle) at night; and even as the shooting of possums seen in the tree branches against the light of the moon. The usage was not isolated to just one activity and has extended to other activities done in the moonlight. This tells us that all related senses are an extended sense from the light of the moon, moonlight.

Answer (score 0):

In Ireland, a job that is not reported to the taxman is called a "nixer". Interestingly, the Irish revenue provides "moonlighting" as a synonym for nixer.

From https://www.revenue.ie/en/corporate/assist-us/reporting-shadow-economy-activity/nixers.aspx

> **What does the term 'nixer' mean in the context of tax and social welfare?**
>
> The term 'nixer' generally refers to part-time work that an individual
> undertakes and the income from which is not reported to relevant authorities
> such as Revenue.

Comment: So what do the Irish call a second job that _is_ reported to the taxman (but perhaps not necessarily to the original employer)?